# Looking for video timeline functionality like clideo

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, video, video-processing

I'm looking to implement a video editing feature like that of featured here https://clideo.com/video-editor.

I'm planning to use Vue 3 with a Laravel backend, but is there an ideal framework to use for a web application like this, or should I just try to reverse engineer/hack my way to a working implementation?

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask, I just haven't been able to find an answer.

Thanks

Comment: I'm working on a simple snip feature and i'm using ffmpeg.wasm to extract the frames and some html/js to control the timeline.

Answer (score -2):

Video editor consist of two important parts
1)A Timeline that represents sequence.
2)A Output window to show output of timeline.
-Clideo uses div and html elements positioning to generate timeline but a better alternative is to use Canvas and draw a timeline on it just like in veed.io
-For video output again you have to use canvas and webGL to draw each and every frame one by one.
you wont be able to edit video on backend and send edited multimedia for each change user makes you need to find a way to do in on client using webcodec.

For the choice of framework if you are having canvas and webGL do all the rendering of timeline and output then it dosent matters you will spend more time with drawing functions.

Answer (score -3):

Almost every video editor has a timeline. But only in some of it (https://wave.video/tools/video-marketing/promo-video-maker) is divided into several ranges. An additional advantage will be the grid on the line. You can also easily manage layers and frames.

Comment: Not helpful and didn't answer the question.